# Pandas transpose rows to columns based on first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe.

```
Column_1   Column_2
Name       Xxxx
Age        28
Gender     M
Name       yyyy
Age        26
Gender     F
```

My expected output is

```
Name   Age   Gender
Xxxx   28    M
yyyy   26    F
```

I tried df.T(), but it's writing each name, age and gender to separate columns.

How to achieve the above output in python/pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
df["idx"] = df.groupby("Column_1").cumcount()

>>> df.pivot("idx", "Column_1", "Column_2").reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
  Age Gender  Name
0  28      M  Xxxx
1  26      F  Yyyy
```

Answer (score 3):

Or try `groupby` with `agg` and `pd.Series.explode`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Column_1').agg(list).T.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
  Age Gender  Name
0  28      M  Xxxx
1  26      F  yyyy
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {
    'Column_1': ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Name', 'Age', 'Gender'],
    'Column_2': ['Xxxx', '28', 'M', 'yyyy', '26', 'F']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('Column_1')['Column_2'].apply(list).to_dict())
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   Age Gender  Name
0  28      M   Xxxx
1  26      F   yyyy
```